# iOS8/Swift Data Persistence after uninstall

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, persistence

I'm developing an iPhone application for iOS8 in Swift. I currently save all the user data through NSUserDefaults and this works completely fine. Once I uninstall the demo app from my phone and reinstall it through XCode6, all the NSUserDefaults are gone, this is expected.

Question:
How do I persist user data after uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store data in the Keychain, Keychain data will persist.